# SQL authentication connection error, suspect characters in PW

Tags: c#, sql, web-config, sqlclient

In web.config:

```
<add name="conn" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=SERVERNAME; Initial Catalog=INITIALDB; UID=username; PWD=+abc-def(;" />
```

I ensured that the username has db_owner role in the INITIALDB, by deleting the database user and recreating it.  I ensured that the username password worked, by connecting to the server via SSMS (using the above UID and PWD) and expanding the database.

Any ideas?  I'm at my wits end and I cannot change the password assigned to me very easily...  I don't think any of those characters need escaping but clearly there is a problem.

UPDATE:

The error had nothing to do with the password characters.  I was getting "Cannot open database ... requested by the login.  The login failed ..." However -- the connection worked perfectly when I removed the "Initial Catalog" or "Database" section from the connection string.  Turns out that the database had a .MDF filename that was different than the name of the database (e.g. my_db_name and db_name.mdf).  Somehow the connection string that specified the Database or Initial Catalog property was unable to connect because of this.  Detaching, changing the MDF filename to be consistent, and re-attaching the database actually sorted the problem.  Strange, right?

Comment: What characters are you using? You may need to connection-string-escape them.

Comment: + - (    the password actually leads with the +   From what I could gather I should only need to escape XML chars that need escaping &amp; &quot; &lt; &rt; etc.  is this not the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the password this way: `&quot;+abc-def(;&quot;`

like:

```
<add name="conn" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=SERVERNAME; Initial Catalog=INITIALDB; UID=username; PWD=&quot;+abc-def(;&quot;" />
```

Comment: I was very excited when I saw this as that was an approach I'd not tried before, but alas, still the same error, actually I did: &quot;+abc-def(&quot;; and your recommendation, and '+abc-def(' to no avail.  I am just going to call it a night I think and ask them to change the password to something more reasonable (even just as a test) in the morning..

Comment: I have an app that takes database info, and in the end it stores everything as a normal connection string. with your data, it generates the string i just posted. Now i have also setup a login with these details and it connects just fine.

Comment: The solution to this problem actually had nothing to do with the password characters.  You're answer is right on however because for one password that included a semicolon I used your approach like so:  'pass;word' and that resolved the issue.  I'll post an update on the question to describe the source of this particular error.

Comment: I do think that your ;&quot; at the end may be transposed and should actually be &quot;; but I haven't tested it.  Thanks for the help!